# Displaying certain list items based on logged in user Asp Net Core 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to figure out the best way to use authentication to control which ul tag is displayed

Curent html

```
 //wrap all this is authentication razor code?
 <!-- START Profile button menu -logged in -->
 <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
     <li class="dropdown-header">Profile</li>
     <li>
         <a tabindex="-1" asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index">
             <i class="si si-envelope-open pull-right"></i>
             <span class="badge badge-primary pull-right">3</span>Inbox
         </a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a tabindex="-1" asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index">
             <i class="si si-user pull-right"></i>
             <span class="badge badge-success pull-right">1</span>Profile
         </a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
             <i class="si si-settings pull-right"></i>Settings
         </a>
     </li>
     <li class="divider"></li>
     <li class="dropdown-header">Actions</li>
     <li>
          <a tabindex="-1" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Lockout">
              <i class="si si-lock pull-right"></i>Lock Account
          </a>
     </li>
     <li>
          <a tabindex="-1" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout">
              <i class="si si-logout pull-right"></i>Log out
          </a>
     </li>
</ul>
<!-- END Profile button menu -logged in-->
<!-- START Profile button menu - not logged in-->
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
     <li class="dropdown-header">Actions</li>
     <li>
         <a tabindex="-1" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">
             <i class="si si-logout pull-right"></i>Login
         </a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a tabindex="-1" asp-area="" asp-controller="Register" asp-action="Register">
            <i class="si si-lock pull-right"></i>Register
         </a>
     </li>
</ul>
<!-- END Profile button menu - not logged in -->
```

I found a blog post by Dave Paquette on custom tag helpers to accomplish this, but I couldn't get it to work. This html is in my partial view of my header navigation so I can't (or don't know how to check for this in the controller) so I opted to test for logged in user using Razor.

I don't see any blogs or tuorials on simple logged in user check. They all have to do with policy's, claims, etc. I just simply want to know if the user is logged in or not and display the ul dependent on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `SignInManager` to see if there is any user logged in. This will use `Claims`. If you are using the `AplicationUser` model you can do the following.

On your razor page use:

```
inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
```

And then:

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    //some html...
}
```